# Sort or Rearrange Rows of a table in angularjs (drag and drop)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-table

I wanted to have the functionality of rearranging rows in a table (sorting rows using drag and drop). 
**And the index of the row arrangement should also change in the model.**

How can I do something similar to this : http://jsfiddle.net/tzYbU/1162/
using Angular Directive?

I am generating table as :

```
<table id="sort" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header-color-green"></th>
      <th ng-repeat="titles in Rules.Titles">{{titles.title}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="rule in Rules.data">
    <tr>
      <td class="center"><span>{{rule.ruleSeq}}</span></td>
      <td ng-repeat="data in rule.ruleData">{{statusArr[data.value]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I did it. See my code below.

HTML

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <table style="width:auto;" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Count</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ui:sortable ng:model="list">
            <tr ng:repeat="item in list" class="item" style="cursor: move;">
                <td>{{$index}}</td>
                <td>{{item}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>{{list}}
        <hr>
</div>
```

Directive (JS)

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui']);

myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["one", "two", "thre", "four", "five", "six"];
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

Comment: Putting the ng:model on the ui:sortable seems to be the key to keeping the index in the model in sync with the DOM sorted order. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea how to handle this without jQuery with pure Angular.js?

Comment: Thank you a lot for this. Just so great that nobody ever happens to mention, it's not JUST the UL/LI-structure that the sortable works with! Just spent a whole lot of hours trying to fix my HTML to work with UL/LI-layout instead of tables, since there are not very good jquery plugin alternatives for column-dragging and ended up scrapping it.

Comment: @Sushrut You should note in your answer that this answer relies on the use of jQuery UI and is not a pure Angular or Javascript solution.

Comment: How can i get the selected and dragged item index and value?   The scenario is 

user1, user2, user3, user4

Move user4 to user2  how can i get these values changed?

Comment: what does this line do "angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);"

Comment: Thanks for this sexy solution using angularjs.
Can you precise the library used for the 'ui' import please ?

Answer (score 11):

There is another library: RubaXa/Sortable: https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable

It is for modern browsers and without jQuery dependency. Included is a angular directive. I'm going to check it out now.

You get good touch support additionally.

Comment: It doesn't look like this supports tables.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Make sure to put the directive on the TBODY element > http://jsbin.com/gebirenoje/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Looks like a solid solution without jQuery dependency. Check out their web site, they have plenty of examples there as well: https://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/

Answer (score 5):

AngularJS was not really built for the *manipulation* of DOM elements, rather to *extend* the HTML of a page.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13151808/171926) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS#The_philosophy_of_Angular) Wikipedia entry.

For DOM manipulation, jQuery/mootools/etc will suite you just fine (hint: the example in your jsFiddle link).

You could probably use AngularJS to keep track of the ordering of your elements to update your model. I'm not sure how to do this using directives, but the following code *may* be useful

```
var MyController = function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.rules = [...];
    ...

}

var updateRules = function(rule, position) {
    //We need the scope
    var scope = angular.element($(/*controller_element*/)).scope(); //controller_element would be the element with ng-controller='MyController'

    //Update scope.rules
}
```

Then when you reorder the list, simply call `updateRules()` with the changed rule and its new position in the model.

Comment: yes i agree, it has to be done by some DOM manipulator like jQuery, but i want it to have the same jQuery function to be inside a angular directive.

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge of AngularJS is _very_ minimal, however, [this page](http://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html) has some code which combines AngularJS with jQuery datepicker. There is a working example too. I'm sure, with a few modifications, it would be possible to combine the jQuery Sortable widget instead.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone else who wants something like this but not understanding the accepted answer. Here is a directive **[UI.Sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable#uisortable-directive)** for AngularJS that allows you to sort an array/ table rows with drag & drop.

**Requirements**

```
JQuery v3.1+ (for jQuery v1.x & v2.x use v0.14.x versions)
JQueryUI v1.12+
AngularJS v1.2+
```

**Usage**

Load the script file: sortable.js in your application: (you can find this **sortable.js** from [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/releases)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="modules/directives/sortable/src/sortable.js"></script>
```

> make sure you have included JQuery, AngularJs and JQueryUI js files in
>   order before this sortable file
>   Add the sortable module as a dependency to your application module:

```
 var myAppModule = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.sortable'])
```

Apply the directive to your form elements:

```
<ul ui-sortable ng-model="items">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

**Developing Notes:**

1. ng-model is required, so that the directive knows which model to update.
2. ui-sortable element should contain only one ng-repeat
3. Filters that manipulate the model (like filter, orderBy, limitTo,...) should be applied in the controller instead of the ng-repeat

> 3rd point is very Important as it took almost an hour to understand
>   why my sorting was not working?? It was because of orderBy in html
>   and that was resetting the sorting again.

For more understanding you can check the detail [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable#uisortable-directive).

Comment: loving the answer awesome

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to sort the rows? If so, use UI-Sortable: [GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)
Demo: codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/jlkhr

Comment: Does UI-Sortable work with Table Rows? Or only List Items?

Comment: I used with Table Rows. It works fine. You can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Along with RubaXa/Sortable there is one more angularjs library avilable that is ***angular-ui-tree***. Along with drag and drop we can arrange elements in a tree structure and we can add and delete elements (nodes)

**Please see the this link for examples**

http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example .

**Please see this for github**

https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree.