# drag and drop table columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I'm using angularjs and have created a table that is filled from a scope object.

It would be really cool if I could somehow manage to add a "drag n drop" function to this, by that I mean the change to order of the columns, and not the order of the rows.

How can I do that?

http://plnkr.co/edit/svSbXBmr2oP0PMDDpHtv?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng:controller="MainCtrl">
<table border="1">
  <thead style="font-weight: bold;">
    <tr>
      <th class="text-right" ng-repeat="column in columnsTest" ng-if="column.checked" ng-bind="column.id"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td ng-repeat="column in columnsTest" ng-if="column.checked">
        {{ getCellValue(row, column) }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<p ng-repeat="c in columnsTest">Column {{$index}}: {{c}}</p>
</div>

<script>
console.clear();

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $parse) {

  $scope.getCellValue = function(row, column) {

    var getter = $parse(column.value);
    return getter(row);

    // Alternatively:
    // return $parse(column.value)(row);
  };

  $scope.columnsTest = [{
    id: 'Value1',
    checked: true,
    value: 'Value1'
  }, {
    id: 'Value2',
    checked: true,
    value: 'Value2'
  }, {
    id: 'Value3',
    checked: true,
    value: 'Value3'
  }];

  $scope.rows = [{
    id: 1,
    "Value1": 911,
    "Value2": 20,
    "Value3": 20
  }, {
    id: 2,
    "Value1": 200,
    "Value2": 20,
    "Value3": 20
  }];
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look for one of the plugins for jQuery that have the feature.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978478/drag-and-drop-to-arrange-table-row-order-in-angularjs

Comment: @epascarello I would like to use angularjs for this, and not some jquery plugin. I tried using https://akottr.github.io/dragtable/ but it didn't work well when the cells where updating

Comment: @JohannesJander Thank you. I will check it out

Comment: @emptyman It is going to require JavaScript of some sort to do it. There is nothing built into Angular/HTML that does this.