# AngularJS | How to include drag and drop list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

How to include drag and drop to my list ?

file: list.tpl.html

```
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Lp.</th>
    <th>Nazwa</th>
    <th>Estymacja</th>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>Ico</th>
    <th>Zaznacz jako wykonane</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <td>{{$index+1}}. </td>
    <td><span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.title}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="done-{{todo.done}}">({{todo.estimates}}h)</span></td>
    <td><span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.date}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{todo.type.gico}} done-{{todo.done}}"></span></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="todo.done" title="Mark Complete" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

file: list-ctrl.js

```
app.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope) { 
 $scope.deleteCompleted = function () {
    $scope.$parent.todos = $scope.$parent.todos.filter(function (item) {
      return !item.done;
    });
  };
});
```

I'm learning AngularJS, so thanks for help !

Comment: From what I understand, you need to use some sort of plugin, and drag and drop is not directly supported. Looks like "angular-dragdrop.js" is one.

Answer (score 0):

I usually dont like adding plugins to my code but in this case you can just add a simple module for drag drop. I use 
[ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)

then you need to simply do

```
    <ul ui-sortable ng-model="items">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

this is for a list... a table I guess shouldnt be really different

also check out this solution:
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614695/sort-or-rearrange-rows-of-a-table-in-angularjs-drag-and-drop)