# How to reorder columns in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-directive

this is my html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive mar0 tablebg table-width">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="field in jsonData.fieldsNameList  track by $index" class="field-name">
                <span ng-click="onclicktableHeader(field)">{{field.fieldName}}</span>                                
                <span class="check-align" ng-if="field.fieldType=='field'"><i ng-click="enableFilter(field)" tooltip="Enable Filtering" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-placement="up" ng-class="{'fa fa-check-square-o': !field.enableFiltering, 'fa fa-plus-circle': field.enableFiltering}"></i></span>
                <span class="check-align" ng-if="field.fieldType=='field'"><i ng-click="enableSort(field)" tooltip="Enable Sorting" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-placement="up" ng-class="{'fa fa-check-square-o': !field.enableSorting, 'fa fa-plus-circle': field.enableSorting}"></i></span>

                <i ng-click="deleteColumn(field)" class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="field in jsonData.fieldsNameList  track by $index">
                {{field.fieldName}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="field in jsonData.fieldsNameList  track by $index">
                {{field.fieldName}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="field in jsonData.fieldsNameList  track by $index">
                {{field.fieldName}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is my array which i am repeating

```
      $scope.jsondata.fieldsNameList = [{ "enableFiltering": false, "enableSorting": false, "fieldId": "56adc5276e65744a03ed0c00", "fieldName": "fnamev2", "fieldType": "field" }, { "enableFiltering": false, "enableSorting": false, "fieldId": "56adc5276e65744a03ed0d21", "fieldName": "fnamev1", "fieldType": "field" }];
```

i want to reorder the columns of table by dragging it left and right, how to do this, and is their any way using angularjs or javascript

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614695/sort-or-rearrange-rows-of-a-table-in-angularjs-drag-and-drop

Comment: thanks but in the above link it is for rows but i want for columns

Comment: Have you considered using smart table (http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/). Here is an example with draggable columns: http://plnkr.co/edit/DRagFo?p=preview

Comment: thank you this is wat i wanted :)