# MVC server side or client side

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am a java developer. Learning angularJs offlate. I need to develop a web application with good dom manipulation on the UI. I plan to use Spring MVC framework on the server side.

Angularjs, backbonejs are predominantly used for Single Page Applications.

I need to achieve a UI like the links below. Can this be achieved by just jquery. I am well acquainted with jquery. And AngularJS seems a little different in syntax and would require much time to learn.

http://demo.songpane.com/#/set/a/i

http://thiagofelix.github.io/hackynote/app/#/

http://igorminar.github.io/Memory-Game/app/

If we just put the mvc aside, for the UI is there much difference between jquery and angularJS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is Angular Js different from jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151725/how-is-angular-js-different-from-jquery)

Comment: short answer; yes it can be achieved through jQuery.