# Trend Analysis - Angular Js Vs JQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I recently got a requirement of analysing the best UI Technologies and to use the best in my project. My project a Single Page Application and I am free to use either JQuery or Angular or both.

Before starting I wanted to know the specialists views of of Stack over flow.

First version of Angularjs published in 2009. It has been almost 4 years and Angular Js is still lagging behind JQuery. On the other hand JQuery has expedited its usage vastly over the years. Do you think angular can compete JQuery in near future?
Suggestions required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is Angular Js different from jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151725/how-is-angular-js-different-from-jquery)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/why-use-angularjs-instead-of-jquery

Comment: This is about the trend not the differences. Please reply if you have any ideas.

Comment: None of the links are about Trend of these technologies.

Comment: If you comapre Angular vs JQuery then probably you are comparing apples and oranges(yes both are fruits i.e ui technologies).

Angular is more about the MVC framework on client side. It gives your code a structure. Jquery is more about direct dom manipulation. With Angular you get many things for free dual bindings, DI. In jquery you have write a lot of code to do similar things. Add to it the advantages of unit testing and end to end testings.

Comment: @User: There are differences between Opinion and Requirement Analysis. I did not ask for any opinion. (It was only for you) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are comparing two completely different things. The purposes of both frameworks are lays on different fields although they are intended for UI.

Angular is the framework that allows you to separate model from view and controllers and structure your code in MVC patterns on the client side. So if you choose angular all your architecture will be build in angular way and you will operate with angular entities.

On the other hand jQuery is just giving you possibility to work with browser API more efficiently on the lower level. It doesn't help you to structure your code (unless your are writing jQuery pluggins). But again - it doesn't give you the MVC(it's actually a bit deeper than classic MVC) approach.

What you really can compare is Angular with other client MVC frameworks such as : Backbone, Ember, etc. Which is also may be a bit controversial regarding Backbone.

And I don't know such a thing that you can compare with jQuery.
So in my opinion they never will be competing on the market.

Hope this will help you to have start point for your further investigation.

Comment: Actually the reason for this idea is that: **1)** By using AngularJS, it seems to be that there is no need to use jQuery or Javascript. Is that true? **2)** For an Asp.NET MVC project, do you suggest Angular JS and do you think that Angular JS's popular trend will continue?

Comment: 1)in general using the jquery along with angular is not "angular way", but there are some cases where you do need to use them together...but to do that properly you need to understand how angular works. Regarding javascript - if you write angular 1 application then you have to write your code using js or any other language that compiles into js. 2) To use or not to use angular depends on what sort browsers you want to cover, cause it might be slow on mobile platforms which supposedly should be fixed in angular 2 which is written on typeScript

Answer (score 1):

**Jquery**

jQuery is a multi-browser JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML

The purpose of jQuery is to make it much easier to use JavaScript on your website.

**Angular**

AngularJS is an open-source JavaScript framework, maintained by Google, that assists with running single-page applications.
AngularJS is a toolset for building the framework most suited to your application development.