# Hide element from loop (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've got this code:

AngularJS:

```
$scope.languages = [
  { language: "English", i18n: "en" },
  { language: "Espanol", i18n: "es" },
  { language: "Polski", i18n: "pl" },
  { language: "Portugues", i18n: "pt" },
  { language: "Svenska", i18n: "se" },
];
```

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="lang in languages" id="langRow_{{lang.i18n}}">
  <a href="#" id="lang_{{lang.i18n}}" ng-click="changeLang(lang.i18n);"><i class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{lang.i18n}} mr-sm"></i>{{lang.language}}</a>
</li>
```

and I want to hide an element from loop, for example:

```
$("#langRow_es").hide();
```

It doesn't work. How to solve this?

Comment: Why not use `ngShow` or `ngHide`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) If you want to use Angular, FORGET JQUERY.

2) USE ANGULAR.

Try this :

```
<li ng-repeat="lang in languages" ng-hide="lang.i18n=='es'" >
```

Comment: Well beginner, remember the rule number one : FORGET JQUERY :) And please validate my answer if you believe it's correct. Cheers!

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151725/how-is-angularjs-different-from-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background the latter is imho a good source even though it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

No Need Of Using Id Operation Here.
But U can use "ng-if" also if we do not want to render the element completely inorder to hide. So we will see all languages other than english.

`<li ng-repeat="lang in languages" ng-if="lang.i18n !=='es'">
      <a href="#" id="lang_{{lang.i18n}}" ng-click="changeLang(lang.i18n);"><i class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{lang.i18n}} mr-sm"></i>{{lang.language}}</a>
    </li>`