# Using Javascript and Jquery in a angular 6 cli project

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular6

I am using angular 6 cli and i want to use jquery and javascript. i imported jquery and bootstrap but still get an error when trying to use jquery. I want to use the code below or convert it to ts. I looked online and followed a couple of suggestions but they didnt work.

when I add the code below to my angular component.ts file it flags error.

```
 $('.editValues').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td.editableColumns').each(function() {
      var html = $(this).html();
      var input = $('<input class="editableColumnsStyle" type="text" />');
      input.val(html);
      $(this).html(input);
    });
  });
```

the following errors are shown

```
ERROR in src/app/_services/user.service.ts(56,5): error TS1003: Identifier expected.
src/app/_services/user.service.ts(56,19): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
src/app/_services/user.service.ts(56,26): error TS1138: Parameter declaration expected.
src/app/_services/user.service.ts(63,4): error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
```

i get these errors when i add that code . ERROR in

```
src/app/_services/user.service.ts(56,5): error TS1003: Identifier expected.
    src/app/_services/user.service.ts(56,13): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
    src/app/_services/user.service.ts(56,20): error TS1138: Parameter declaration expected.
    src/app/_services/user.service.ts(56,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    src/app/_services/user.service.ts(57,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

Comment: You have problems with TypeScript, not @angular/cli. Probably it doesn't know what is $. Did you install jquery and types for it?

Comment: @Drag13 Thanks for the reply, i have the following import import * as $ from 'jquery'; and in my package.json has "@types/jquery": "^3.3.6",

Comment: Ok, what code do you have on line 56?

Comment: @Drag13 $('.editValues').click(function () {

Comment: Quite strange... Cold you change that block for this: 
$('.test').click(() => false); 
and check if any error appears

Comment: @Drag13 i am updating my post to show the error that displays

Comment: show please full code of the service

Comment: You shouldn't really be using jQuery like this with Angular

Comment: @phuzi yes, he shouldn't but this is not the answer)

Comment: @phuzi Hi, i tried to find a similar way to convert a table to editable on click but cant find anything that works. what do you suggest instead of this.

Comment: @Drag13 , that's why it's a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery code is in a class body, where the compiler is expecting a constructor, accessor, property or a method (*src/app/_services/user.service.ts(63,4): error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected*).

You need to put it inside a method.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, OnViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './app-my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-my-component.css'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnViewInit {
  constructor(private store: Store<any>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to store
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe from store
  }

  ngOnViewInit() {
    // Put your jQuery code here
  }
}
```

Note that using jQuery with modern Angular is not really recommended and against best practises. Read more: [Best Practice of Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411744/best-practice-of-angular-2)

Comment: do you mean like this import * as $ from 'jquery'; thats my import statement

Comment: No, your Angular app has classes and you can't put anything but constructors, accessors, properties or methods in the body of your class.

Comment: Thanks that worked but i have just one more question. this method i put it in is it called on init because the method is showing unused

Comment: IIRC you should put it in ngOnViewInit as the DOM view has not been loaded yet when you run ngOnInit and jQuery needs access to it.